# Reset a form with Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, reset

I'm trying to reset a form with Jquery in a web application I'am developing with Java and Tapestry. The problem is that Tapestry doesn't provide any kind of method to reset a form, so I need to create a JS module for it.

I have about 4-5 forms in my application with different id's, so I tried this:

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {

    return function() {
        $("form").on("submit", function() {
            if (!$("form-group").hasClass("has-errors") && !$("div").hasClass("alert")){
                $("form").reset();
            }
        });
    }

})
```

This is my first time with JQuery, so it doesn't works. What I'm trying to do is set a callback when the submit button of the form gets hitted.
This is my button declaration inside the form:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
```

I have only one form on each page. I think this is quite simple, but i can't get it to work. Anyone can give me some help with this? Thanks.

Comment: you can clear a form this way too -- $('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val(""); -- providing you add the input types separated by comas. http://jsfiddle.net/pxqhb5k6/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.reset()` method is not a jQuery method, and that's why it wouldn't work with a jQuery object. You can, however, refer to the DOM node in the jQuery object and then use the native JS method on it, i.e.: `$("form")[0].reset();`.

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {

    return function() {
        $("form").on("submit", function() {
            if (!$("form-group").hasClass("has-errors") && !$("div").hasClass("alert")){
                $("form")[0].reset();
            }
        });
    }

})
```

However, I generally consider a form reset button unnecessary and in fact, [detrimental to user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93671/do-we-really-require-a-reset-button-for-form-fields). For majority (I'd say 99.9%) of use cases, when a user starts typing in a form they do not have the intention of completely erasing their data, and so the reset button, when clicked on by mistake (especially if the action is not made clear through UI design), will erase the user's input much to their frustration (and with no "undo" recourse).

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working fine. I don't know that `.reset()` is not a jQuery method. Yes, I know that a reset button it's not very user friendly, but I'm doing a form with an AJAX message on success, so if the transaction with the database was successful, the page resets the form and displays an AJAX Bootstrap success-alert, so you can dismiss the alert or return to the previous page or you can fill again the form (in this case to add an sports event to database). Thanks for the link to the ux info!

Comment: @EliasGarciaMariño My bad, on closer inspection you aren't implementing a close button feature, but a callback that resets a form :) that should please the UI/UX gurus hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for latest versions of jQuery (2021).

```
$("#myForm").trigger("reset");
```

or simply only JS

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

The *reset* function (still) does not exist in `jQuery`. However there are couple of way you can achieve form resetting. The code below, for example, loops through every element of the form and calls the DOM `reset` JavaScript method.

```
jQuery('#form').each(function(){
  this.reset();
});
```

A more simpler way would be to do something like:

```
  jQuery("#form").reset();
```

In this case you should implement your own `reset` method like this:

```
jQuery.fn.reset = function () {
  jQuery(this).each(function() { 
    this.reset(); 
  });
}
```

Another way to implement your own `reset` form method is:

```
 jQuery.fn.reset = function(fn) {
   return fn ? this.bind("reset", fn) : this.trigger("reset");
 };
```

This would allow you to attach a code to a `reset` function:

```
 jQuery("#form").reset(function(){ 
   /* some other code */ 
 });
```

You can (and still this is recommended way to do the things) use a simple HTML input of type `reset` - it will do the same even on browsers who have JavaScript disabled.